# Google custom search submit callback

Tags: javascript, search, google-custom-search

I have this somewhere on my page:

```
<gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>
```

And this is somewhere else on the same page:

```
<gcse:searchresults></gcse:searchresults>
```

It is hidden. I want to slide it in when the search result comes from Google. How can I do this?

Thank you for your time
Ropo

Comment: What do you mean by `Slide It In`?

Comment: I want to use jquery animation to let the div with the search result slide in from the right. I don't want to re-load the page. I want to retrieve the result with ajax, but need a callback when the result there